Manual mapping of response to data model using Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch
i am to declare Body as JsonElement and inspect its properties to parse the contained value as string or string[], depending on the token type. but I am stuck. My body response from elasticsearch can be string or string[] but my data model only set as string[]. below are my snippet
Model:
public class ElasticsearchData
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("url")]
        public string Url { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public string[] Body { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("creation_time")]
        public string Creation_Time { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public int NumberOfDoc { get; set; }

        public ElasticsearchData()
        {
            Title = string.Empty;
            Url = string.Empty;
            Creation_Time = string.Empty;
            NumberOfDoc = 0;
        }
    }

Snippet:
 var request = new SearchRequest("search-search-ntlm")
                {
                    Query = new MatchQuery("body")
                    {
                        Field = "body",
                        Query = query,
                        Fuzziness = new Fuzziness("auto")
                    },
                    Highlight = new Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch.Core.Search.Highlight
                    {
                        Type = "plain",
                        PreTags = new[] { "<tag1>" },
                        PostTags = new[] { "</tag1>" },
                        Encoder = Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch.Core.Search.HighlighterEncoder.Html,
                        Fields = new Dictionary<Field, HighlightField>
                        {
                            {
                                "body", new HighlightField
                                {
                                    Type = HighlighterType.Plain,
                                    PreTags = new[] { "<strong>" },
                                    PostTags = new[] { "</strong>" },
                                    FragmentSize = 150,
                                    Fragmenter = HighlighterFragmenter.Span,
                                    NumberOfFragments = 3,
                                    NoMatchSize = 150,
                                    HighlightQuery = new MatchQuery("body")
                                    {
                                        Query = query
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
                
                var response = client.SearchAsync<ElasticsearchData>(request);

sample response:
{
"_index": "search-ocr-poc",
"_id": "5c87196f-eb64-4b2e-8570-5b41ef1f7759",
"_score": 2.591784,
"_source": {
"creation_time": "2024-03-28T07:39:05Z",
"size": 1847715,
"server_relative_url": "/sites/COPS/Documents/1.png",
"id": "5c87196f-eb64-4b2e-8570-5b41ef1f7759",
"type": "File",
"title": "1.png",
"body": "Oops Access denied er Please check with your System Administrator on System Access,, Thank you",
"_timestamp": "2024-04-01T04:11:07Z",
"url": "/sites/COPS/Documents/1.png"
}

